# Android keeps downloading an unknown file

Tags: samsung, downloading, antivirus

about a few days ago i discovered an unknown file in my downloads on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S21FE).

It could not open it on my phone so i just transfered it onto my pc to open it. It contains somethig that looks like Hex-Values "91e1f39[...]092abb0e2333b8f2e" (in the [...] are more of this).

I doesnt have any extension, or information where it comes from. It just has a name "testing". When i delete it, it randomly appears on my phone a few days later...

Do you have any idea what this could be?

Thanks

Comment: This may be interesting for this: 
once i was in a public space i got bombarded with bluetooth-pairing requests. like someone is using a Flipper-Zero with Bluetooth-LE-Spam. 
I dont know which scenario came first..